# How can I make this relation into the third normal form (3NF)?

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization, 3nf

I want to normalise this table and so far I managed to get it up to 2NF but I'm very confused on how I can possibly make it a 3NF. Primary keys in bold.

1NF: Appointment (**StaffNo**, DName, PatName, **PatNum**, PatTelNo, ApptDateTime, **RoomNo**, RoomExt)

2NF:

Doctor (**StaffNo**, DName)

Patient (PatName, **PatNum**, PatTelNo)

Room(**RoomNo**, RoomExt)

Appointment(**StaffNo**, **PatNum**, **RoomNo**, ApptDateTime)

I'm not really able to see transitive dependencies here. How am I able to make this into a 3NF?

Edit:

I did some thinking but I'd like to verify if my answer is correct:

Doctor (**StaffNo**, DName)

Patient (**PatNum**, PatTelNo)

PatientDetails (**PatTelNo**, PatName)

Room(**RoomNo**, RoomExt)

Appointment(**StaffNo**, **PatNum**, **RoomNo**, ApptDateTime)

Comment: For any normalization you should ALWAYS start by listing the functional dependencies.  Your edit contradicts my common sense, but without FDs, it's just my assumptions against yours.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not really able to see transitive dependencies here. How am I able to make this into a 3NF?

I have to make an educated and experienced guess about the functional dependencies, but based on that guesswork, I'd say you misunderstand several things about normalization.

You have these things under the heading "2NF", but

Doctor (**StaffNo**, DName) is probably in 6NF,

Patient (PatName, **PatNum**, PatTelNo) is probably in 5NF,

Room(**RoomNo**, RoomExt) is probably in 6NF, and

Appointment(**StaffNo**, **PatNum**, **RoomNo**, ApptDateTime) is probably in 6NF.

It looks like you said to yourself, "I see no partial-key dependencies, so each of these is in 2NF." But the absence of partial-key dependencies doesn't mean that; it means that a relation is in *at least* 2NF.

A relation that's in 5NF is also in 4NF, BCNF, 3NF, 2NF, and 1NF. The idea that you can normalize a relation to 2NF *and no higher*, followed by normalization to 3NF *and no higher*, is a common misunderstanding.

Your later edit is a almost certainly a mistake. The only functional dependency that can justify it is PatTelNo -> PatName, which is simply not true in the general case.

You provide no functional dependencies, perhaps because you don't know what they are, or because you think they're not important, or because you think you can base normalization on attribute names. But you can't do normalization without knowing the functional dependencies; they're not just important, they're critical; and attribute names have nothing to do with it.